# How to use preg_replace in foreach loop in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, preg-replace

I'm a beginner in PHP.

My purpose is to print three sentences with a multi-dimensional array :

1. cats are smelly
2. birds are beautiful
3. snails are sticky

But the only sentence I'm able to print is "cats are smelly". I've tried many things. So here is the code:

```
<?php
$sentence = 'dogs are sweet';

$animals = array('@dogs@' => array('cats', 'birds', 'snails'),
                 '@sweet@' => array('smelly', 'beautiful', 'sticky'));

    foreach ($animals as $key => $value)
    {
        foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue)
        {
            $sentence = preg_replace($key, $subvalue, $sentence);
        }
    }
    echo $sentence . '</br>';

?>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: After it completes the first replace the sentence no longer contains dog or sweet. You will need maybe an array of sentences. $newSentences[] = preg_replace ....

Comment: put this in the inner foreach `echo  preg_replace($key, $subvalue, $sentence) ."<br>\n";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple layers as to why your solution doesn't work.

- The sentence is only echoed once
- Sentence is being replaced, so once "dogs" is replaced, it won't replace anything else because dogs isn't in the sentence anymore.
- The script loops through the animals array only once.
- Any item is replaced with any item (You specified you want cats to be smelly, birds to be beautiful and snails to be sticky, this means to compare index 0 of the first array with index 0 of the second array, index 1 with index 1, etc.).

I changed your script slightly to make sure it loops through the list thrice, for each time it echoes the output and the sentence is reset to it's default value so it can be changed again.

```
$animals = array('@dogs@' => array('cats', 'birds', 'snails'),
                 '@sweet@' => array('smelly', 'beautiful', 'sticky'));

for ($i = 0; $i < count(reset($animals)); $i++) {
  $sentence = 'dogs are sweet';
  foreach ($animals as $key => $value)
  {
      foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue)
      {
        if ($subkey === $i) {
          $sentence = preg_replace($key, $subvalue, $sentence);
        }
      }
  }

  echo $sentence . "<br />";
}
```

The part `count(reset($animals))` counts the value of the first element of the `$animals` array. So in this case `array('cats', 'birds', 'snails')`. The script assumes the first and the second array are always equal in size.

The if statement in the secondary foreach loop is to make sure the right element from one array is matched with the right element from the other.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's not an answer, it's a lesson. So it helps me a lot, and it shows me all the thinking process, which is the most important i guess. I tried to use a for loop and a count(), but it didn't work cause i wasn't writing it in the right way ! I'm pretty sure there are other ways to get the same result, but this one is the one i needed !